# Windows: Is there NPM modules that can getActiveWindow, and setWindowPos

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have a project exclusively for **Windows** that needs the following:

```
1 - Get the active window
2 - Get the dimension of the active window
3 - From the dimension I get, update the (x, y, w, h)
4 - Set the active window to 'restore' mode
5 - Set the new position of the active window
```

I am looking for any modules that can do this and found [winctl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winctl) but I can't make it work.

**QUESTION**
Are there any modules that can access the Windows active window?
If there is, can you please provide a code sample?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solve my issue by using [ffi-napi](https://github.com/node-ffi-napi/node-ffi-napi).
I added comments on the code to make it easy to understand.

```
const ffi = require('ffi-napi');

// create foreign function
const user32 = new ffi.Library('user32', {
  'GetForegroundWindow': ['long', []],
  'ShowWindow': ['bool', ['long', 'int']],
  'GetWindowRect': ['bool', ['long', 'pointer']],
  'SetWindowPos': ['bool', ['long', 'long', 'int', 'int', 'int', 'int', 'uint']]
});

// create rectangle from pointer
const pointerToRect = function (rectPointer) {
  const rect = {};
  rect.left = rectPointer.readInt16LE(0);
  rect.top = rectPointer.readInt16LE(4);
  rect.right = rectPointer.readInt16LE(8);
  rect.bottom = rectPointer.readInt16LE(12);
  return rect;
}

// obtain window dimension
const getWindowDimensions = function (handle) {
  const rectPointer = Buffer.alloc(16);
  const getWindowRect = user32.GetWindowRect(handle, rectPointer);
  return !getWindowRect
    ? null
    : pointerToRect(rectPointer);
}

// get active window
const activeWindow = user32.GetForegroundWindow();

// get window dimension
const activeWindowDimensions = getWindowDimensions(activeWindow);

// get active window width and height
const activeWindowWidth = activeWindowDimensions.right - activeWindowDimensions.left;
const activeWindowHeight = activeWindowDimensions.bottom - activeWindowDimensions.top;

// center the active window on the screen
const activeWindowX = (1920 / 2) - (activeWindowWidth / 2);
const activeWindowY = (1080 / 2) - activeWindowHeight / 2);

// force active window to restore mode
user32.ShowWindow(activeWindow, 9);

// set window position based on bounds values
user32.SetWindowPos(
  activeWindow,
  0,
  activeWindowX,
  activeWindowY,
  activeWindowWidth,
  activeWindowHeight,
  0x4000 | 0x0020 | 0x0020 | 0x0040
);
```

I use this code on my small project called [Sōkan](https://github.com/genesisneo/sokan).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can get or set to window position by using `remote` and `getFocusedWindow()`.

```js
const remote = require('electron').remote;
let win = remote.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();
```

**BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow()**
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#browserwindowgetfocusedwindow

```js
console.log(win.getPosition());
win.setPosition(0, 0);
```

**win.getPosition()**
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#wingetposition

**win.setPosition()**
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsetpositionx-y-animate

But be careful when using `remote`. Currently, Electron makes it a security recommendation with "Disable the remote module".

**Checklist: Security Recommendations**
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#checklist-security-recommendations

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but correct me if I’m wrong. As what I understand about BrowserWindow is that it’s  limited only for Electron App Window and not the Window outside it (e.g.: Notepad, File Explorer, Calculator, ...). I am looking for something that can manipulate Window outside Electron 

Comment: I'm sorry. That would not be possible in only Electron, as you say. Getting a window 
HWND from another application means that you need to use the Win32/Win64 API directly, such as "FindWindowEx". After all, you'll have to find a node module that can do this, or make it yourself.